# Java, Tracing Recursion on Rat Maze

Tags: java, recursion, trace

I was working on the Rat Maze problem (you can move right or down if 1, and no where if 0). I had issues that my result would not return up the stack, I traced it and everything seemed fine, then i changed my code and it worked and I was not understanding how my trace is incorrect.

I will post 3 versions of the code, first correct then 2 incorrect. My question is concerning what the proper trace of each recursive code is so that I can next time correctly trace my own code and understand that I am tracing through it correctly to find an error.

I should mention result is the number of paths possible to reach [n-1][m-1]

***Correct Code***

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {  
public static int findpath(int [][] arr){
   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;
   int result = 0;
   return findpathHelper(arr, row, col, result);

}

public static int findpathHelper(int [][] arr, int row, int col, int result){

System.out.println(row);
System.out.println(col);
System.out.println();

if(col == arr[row].length-1 && row == arr.length-1){
  System.out.println("Result: " +result);
   return result+1;
}

if(row+1 != arr.length && arr[row+1][col] != 0){      
  result = findpathHelper(arr, row+1, col, result);
}

if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  result = findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}


return result;    
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int [][] path = {{1,1,1,1},
                {0,1,1,1},
                {1,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1}};

   System.out.println(findpath(path));         
  }
}
```

***Incorrect Code 1***
Result will always be 0 up the call stack, even after being updated in base case
I simply got rid of 'result =' in recursive cases

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class Solution {  
  public static int findpath(int [][] arr){
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int result = 0;
   return findpathHelper(arr, row, col, result);

 }

public static int findpathHelper(int [][] arr, int row, int col, int result){

System.out.println(row);
System.out.println(col);
System.out.println();

if(col == arr[row].length-1 && row == arr.length-1){
  System.out.println("Result: " +result);
   return result+1;
}

if(row+1 != arr.length && arr[row+1][col] != 0){      
  findpathHelper(arr, row+1, col, result);
}

if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}
return result;    
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [][] path = {{1,1,1,1},
                {0,1,1,1},
                {1,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1}};

  System.out.println(findpath(path));         
 }
}
```

***Incorrect Code 2***
In base case I got rid of return and instead am using return+=1,
in first call stack it is 1 but as it goes back up the stack it returns to being 0.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class Solution {  
  public static int findpath(int [][] arr){
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int result = 0;
   return findpathHelper(arr, row, col, result);

 }

public static int findpathHelper(int [][] arr, int row, int col, int result){

System.out.println(row);
System.out.println(col);
System.out.println();

if(col == arr[row].length-1 && row == arr.length-1){
  System.out.println("Result: " +result);
   result+=1;
}

if(row+1 != arr.length && arr[row+1][col] != 0){      
  return = findpathHelper(arr, row+1, col, result);
}

if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  return = findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}
return result;    
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [][] path = {{1,1,1,1},
                {0,1,1,1},
                {1,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1}};

  System.out.println(findpath(path));         
 }
}
```

***Aditional Edit***
Going of the 2nd incorrect code, if I add the return = on the recursive cases but not the base case the code still seems fine
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
class Solution {  
  public static int findpath(int [][] arr){
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int result = 0;
   return findpathHelper(arr, row, col, result);

 }

public static int findpathHelper(int [][] arr, int row, int col, int result){

System.out.println(row);
System.out.println(col);
System.out.println();

if(col == arr[row].length-1 && row == arr.length-1){
  System.out.println("Result: " +result);
   result+=1;
}

if(row+1 != arr.length && arr[row+1][col] != 0){      
  result = findpathHelper(arr, row+1, col, result);
}

if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  result = findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}
return result;    
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [][] path = {{1,1,1,1},
                {0,1,1,1},
                {1,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1}};

  System.out.println(findpath(path));         
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah the classic mistake.
You forgot to return your result from inside the if conditions.

You have this :

```
if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}
```

What you want is this:

```
if(col+1 != arr[row].length && arr[row][col+1] != 0){     
  return findpathHelper(arr, row,col+1, result);
}
```